# How to change OS boot queue (NOOBS, Raspberry Pi 3)?

Tags: noobs

How to manage the queue of operating systems in NOOBS on Raspberry pi 3?
I need to change the priorities of boot to another operating system after each reboot[image: Screen for example]

Comment: Ditch NOOBS, switch to the follow-on which is called PINN. It has four years of extra development and includes a bunch of features to make it easier to use. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=142574

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of NOOBS (and PINN) is that the OS selection is based on the partition order on the SD-Card and as such cannot be changed.

My recommendation is never to use multiple operating systems on one card in anything other than dire emergency or for testing / playing as its to easy to loose / damage / wear out a card through heavy use and it takes much much longer to recover.

My second recommendation is to stop using NOOBS A.S.A.P. as (I believe) development has ended (even RPF say to use the [new imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)) and move to [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) as this gives a significantly larger functionality (inc backups / restores / copies etc).

The closest ways I can think of doing this in PIONN would be:

- Use the 'sticky O/S' function.  This stops the PINN menu showing and jumps direct to the selected OS (but still supports the 'shift key' functionality to get back to PINN
- Use the PINN command line option *partition=< part number >* to force boot to a given OS if nothing is selected from the start up screen
- PINN will boot to the last used OS by default so just wait a little while

Answer (score 0):

Both NOOBS & PINN will boot to the last selected OS.

The only option to change is to select the NOOBS manager on boot.